# Orthogonal Complement of Upper Triangular Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

So I wish to find the orthogonal complement with respect to $\tau (A,B) = trace (A^tB)$.

Firstly, can I say that we want to find all matrices $A$ such that $tr(A^tX) = 0$ where $X$ is an Upper triangular matrix, and this is the same (by properties of trace) as saying we want to find all matrices $A$ such that $tr(AX) = 0$ where $X$ is an Upper triangular matrix. (I just think it is easier to visualize it this way)
For upper triangular we must worry about $E-{ii}$ and $E_{ij}$ such that $j > i$ where $E_{ij}$ is the matrix with one in the $i,j$ position, zero elsewhere.

So for the matrix $A$ we need all $a_{ii} = 0$ and all $a_{ij} = 0$ for $i>j$ ?
So the orthogonal complement is the space of strictly upper triangular matrices?

Comment: Are you saying that "by the properties of trace", $trace(A^TX) = trace(AX)$?  This is false.

Comment: ah yes ok thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this problem is simply to note that
$$
\operatorname{trace}(A^TX) = \sum_{i,j = 1}^n a_{ij}x_{ij}
$$
in other words, $\tau$ is "just the dot-product".

As an orthogonal complement, you should end up with just the strictly **lower**-triangular matrices.